# slow application when use setImageBitmap in recyclerview android

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

I'm using BitmapFactory.decodeFile to set image in imageview in recyclerview it work but slow app when i scroll so i'm using picasso library to load images for my app but it doesn't load image

MyAdapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewMolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.textView3.setText(personArrayList.get(position).name);
    int mod=Integer.parseInt(personArrayList.get(position).how);
    mod=mod-(mod%5);
    holder.textView4.setText(mod+"");
    if(!personArrayList.get(position).pathImage.isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(holder.imageView5.getContext())
                .load(personArrayList.get(position).pathImage)
                .fit()
                .into(holder.imageView5);
    }
    /*
    it is work but slow
    holder.imageView5.setImageBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(personArrayList.get(position).pathImage));
    */


}
```

Comment: You can have information from https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: i'm loading image  from storage

Comment: You can use above link to show image efficiently in android

Comment: it is working thank you

Comment: Pleasure is all mine!!!